# HTML Embedded SWF file unable to load within controller

Tags: html, maven, spring-mvc, flash, intellij-idea

Whenever I launch the HTML directly into the browser it loads the SWF fine, however whenever I go to the respective mapping(ie. when spring runs )(localhost:8080/testSWF)) it says unable to load SWF.

Here is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags always come first -->
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="fragments/header-loggedin :: header-loggedin"/>
<h1>Test Biology Quiz</h1>


<br /><br />
<div class="row">

    <div class="clearfix bottom-space"></div>

    <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,19,0" width="1000" height="600">
        <param name="movie" value="testQuiz.swf"/>
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <embed src="testQuiz.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="1000" height="600"></embed>
    </object>

</div>
<div class="clearfix bottom-space"></div>

<div th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer"/>


<!-- jQuery first, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vZ2WRJMwsjRMW/8U7i6PWi6AlO1L79snBrmgiDpgIWJ82z8eA5lenwvxbMV1PAh7" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Controller just contains the mapping for /testSWF

```
@RequestMapping((value = "/testSWF", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String testSWFFile(Model model){ return "/testSWF"; }
```

If you need more information please let me know, thanks in advance.